# Trouble with using function in cmath library

Tags: c++, cmath

Hey guys (and gals) so I'm working on my homework assignment and I'm mostly done except for I can't figure out how to use one of the functions in the cmath library to combine two equations into one. I'll copy and paste the homework instructions followed by my code and the part where I'm having difficulty. The part in bold & italics is what I'm stumped on.

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

If the user chooses a-h, the program should then ask the user to enter their weight (ask politely) and the speed at which they wish to travel (in miles per hour).  Now you have all the data you need from the user:  the planet they wish to travel to, their weight (in lbs on Earth) and the speed at which they wish to travel (in miles per hour).

Using the data the user input and the table on the next page calculate the user's weight on the planet they chose as well as the travel time from earth.

NOTE:  The table shows the distance each planet is from the Sun.  In addition we're technically calculating the distance between the orbits of the two planets.

Use these equations:

1.Weight on New Planet = Weight on Earth * Surface Gravity of New Planet

***2.Distance between Planets (if Earth is further from sun) = Distance from Earth to Sun - Distance from New Planet to Sun***

***3.Distance between Planets (if New Planet is further from sun) = Distance from New Planet to Sun - Distance from Earth to Sun***

4. Travel Time (in hours) = Travel Distance (in miles)/Rate (miles per hour)

***HINT:  Think about how you might be able to use one of the Math functions in the cmath library to combine #2 & #3 into one calculation***

**CODE:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
string planetName;
char userSelection;
double weightEarth, weightNewPlanet, numSpeed, surfGrav, distSun, numHours, numDays, numYears, distanceBetweenPlanets = 0;

cout << "Welcome to INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL PROGRAM!" << endl
     << "This program enables you to find out your travel time to the planet" << endl
     << "you want to travel to as well as your weight on that planet." << endl
     << "Please enjoy the program and find the perfect planet for you!" << endl << endl << endl
     << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL MENU" << endl
     << "--------------------------" << endl
     << "a) Mercury" << endl
     << "b) Venus" << endl
     << "c) Earth" << endl
     << "d) Mars" << endl
     << "e) Jupiter" << endl
     << "f) Saturn" << endl
     << "g) Uranus" << endl
     << "h) Neptune" << endl
     << "q) quit" << endl << endl
     << "Select a planet to travel to or q to quit the program: " << endl;
cin >> userSelection;

if (userSelection >= 'a' && userSelection <= 'h')
{
    cout << "Please enter your weight (in lbs): " << endl;
    cin >> weightEarth;
    cout << "Please enter the speed (in mile per hour) that you would like to travel at: " << endl << endl;
    cin >> numSpeed;

    if (userSelection == 'a')
    {
        planetName = "Mercury";
        distSun = 36;
        surfGrav = 0.27;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'b')
    {
        planetName = "Venus";
        distSun = 67;
        surfGrav = 0.86;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'c')
    {
        planetName = "Earth";
        distSun = 93;
        surfGrav = 1.00;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'd')
    {
        planetName = "Mars";
        distSun = 141;
        surfGrav = 0.37;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'e')
    {
        planetName = "Jupiter";
        distSun = 483;
        surfGrav = 2.64;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'f')
    {
        planetName = "Saturn";
        distSun = 886;
        surfGrav = 1.17;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'g')
    {
        planetName = "Uranus";
        distSun = 1782;
        surfGrav = 0.92;
    }

    else if (userSelection == 'h')
    {
        planetName = "Neptune"; 
        distSun = 2793;
        surfGrav = 1.44;
    }

    distanceBetweenPlanets = std::abs(93 - distSun);

    /*if (userSelection <= 'b')
    {
        distanceBetweenPlanets = 93 - distSun;
    }

    else if (userSelection > 'b')
    {
        distanceBetweenPlanets = distSun - 93;
    }*/

    weightNewPlanet = weightEarth * surfGrav;
    numHours = (distanceBetweenPlanets / numSpeed) * 1000000;
    numDays = (numHours / 24);
    numYears = (numDays / 365);


    cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL:  Earth to " << planetName << endl
        << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl
        << "Your weight on " << planetName << ":      " << fixed << setprecision(2) << weightNewPlanet << " lbs" << endl << endl
        << "Your travel time to " << planetName << ":" << endl
        << "    In Hours: " << fixed << setprecision(0) << numHours << " hours" << endl
        << "    In Days : " << numDays << " days" << endl
        << "    In Years : " << fixed << setprecision(2) << numYears << " years" << endl << endl;
}

else if (userSelection == 'q')
    {
        cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using the program!" << endl;
    }

else
    {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid selection." << endl;
    }

//system("PAUSE");
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: a couple of points - first, in reading it over, the distances seem to be in the wrong unit (are you missing a significant factor of 10?).  Also, I'd question the logic of calculating the distance as instructed, as it seems to assume a planetary alignment. That said, the hint may just be to one-line it, using something like isgreater(x,y)

Comment: Hi John, in regard to the distances, they're actually in millions, but my professor didn't want us to write out the entire thing for each one so for example Mercury is 36000000 (she doesn't want commas in final display either). 

I got the formula figured out just need to format my output correctly and I think I should be good. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Why not `std::abs(a - b)`? Where `a` and `b` are the 2 distances, doesn't matter the order.

Comment: @sharyex - good point, but not std::, from cmath lib :)

Comment: @John, `std::` and `<cmath>` are not mutually exclusive. In fact, `<cmath>` requires things to be declared in `std`.

Comment: @chris - True, but for the assignment's hint, it would reinforce it - in fact, my hat tip to sharyex for recalling abs(), it's ALSO a cmath function, and more elegant than my first (and less snarky than my second)

Comment: @John, disregard my previous comments about not knowing about abs. I discovered a slide in one of our powerpoint lectures that talks about it! I'm going to try it out and I'll update my code in my original post for you to take a look. sharyex, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given the comment above, you may be looking for:

```
isgreater(distSun, 93) ? (distSun - 93) : (93 - distSun)
```

or, if you really want to tweak the teacher:

```
pow( -1, isgreater( distSun, 93 ) ) * (93 - distSun)
```

all assuming 93 is the Earth distance

Comment: Hey @John, I ended up doing the following as that's what we've learned so far: 


          `if (userSelection <= 'b')
  {
   distanceBetweenPlanets = 93 - distSun;
  }

  else if (userSelection > 'b' && userSelection <= 'h')
  {
   distanceBetweenPlanets = distSun - 93;
  }`

Comment: sounds good - lets the teacher know you've been paying attention :) (edit: but I'd drop the && - unnecessary use of resources, 'q' is otherwise handled)

Comment: dropped the `&& userSelection <= 'h'` portion!

Comment: you may want to consider Sharyex's comment and use abs()... it's elegant, and hit's the hint dead center

Comment: then maybe you weren't paying attention - it's in the cmath library he said to "think about" above

Comment: "I haven't learned that yet in my class" no time like the present to learn. Some instructors like it when you teach yourself. Those that don't probably shouldn't be instructors.

Comment: NOTE: I completely overlooked a slide in our lecture powerpoint that talks about using abs!!! @John and user4581301